# Do you need to disconnect battery on older cars when not using car for prolonged time?

Tags: battery

I read that you should disconnect a car batteries negative cable if not using a car for extended periods as this could lead to electrical devices draining the battery especially in new cars with a lot of electronics.

However apparently you do not need to do this with older cars, perhaps because there are less electronics.  Does that mean if I have an old car such as my 1999 civic vti,  I can leave the battery connected and not running for 6-12 months then expect that the car will still start up on crank without the battery being drained and a need for a jump start?

I had the impression that most cars including old needed a jump start when not used for a long time.

Comment: You should use a maintenance battery charger instead......I have used these for cars and lawn tractors, they are the best solution for your situation....https://www.harborfreight.com/automatic-battery-float-charger-42292.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With older cars, the only likely key-off drain would be the clock, and maybe feed to the radio for maintaining presets, which won't add up to anything significant, but the battery itself has a self-discharge rate, and for a period of several months or more, I'd be either removing the battery and storing where it could be periodically checked and recharged, or connecting a battery tender (monitor + low current charger) if it's left in place, or you'll find the battery fully discharged, and even though it will start and begin to recover with a jump, the battery capacity tends to suffer with deep discharges.

Comment: Just to see I've understood you.  You are saying that after 6-12 months the clock and radio would unlikely cause it to drain, however after 6-12 months the car may not start on crank because the battery may have self discharged and hence there will be a need for a jump start? thanks.

Comment: Yes, Clock and radio drain wouldn't fully discharge a battery over a few months.  I wouldn't leave a battery unmonitored for more than that, even if disconnected. If it's a new battery it may survive, but older batteries tend to worsen their self-discharge characteristics, probably because of contamination of the electrolyte. My lawn tractor, motorcycles and vehicles not used during winter all have their batteries in the basement during winter. I can then check them every month or so, and charge them if needed.